# howt to full synchronise outlook calender with sharepoint calender

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, outlook

how can I synchronise my Outlook calender with SharePoint2013 calender programmatically  , full synchronisation , it's mean with all available information like members ,name of meeting ...
and If the event is changed on my personal Outlook calendar, it will  be automatically updated on the SharePoint calendar.
best regards

Comment: http://www.ehow.com/how_7236487_add-sharepoint-calendar-using-outlook.html I want to do the same think but with programmatically way , any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a half solution , wich i succed to synchronise the calenders but , the show roles it steel not resolved .

i put my steps if any one need it .

I create this function to get all my outlook event information

```
List<Calender> calender = new List<Calender>();
        List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

        foreach (Appointment appointment in _service.FindItems(
         WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new ItemView(int.MaxValue)))
        {
            Calender c = new Calender();
            items.Add(appointment);
            _service.LoadPropertiesForItems(items, PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
            c.location = appointment.Location;
            c.start = appointment.Start;
            c.Title = appointment.Subject;
            c.end = appointment.End;
            c.Category = appointment.Categories.ToString();

            c.Description = appointment.Body;
            calender.Add(c);
        }
        return calender;
```

and add it to my SharePoint calender

```
public void addEvent(Calender c)
    {

        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            using (SPSite elevatedSite = new SPSite(@"http://sp-88/Lists"))
            {


                //for all sites/users show "occupé"
                using (SPWeb web = elevatedSite.OpenWeb())
                {
                 web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    SPList list = web.Lists["Calendrier"];

                     SPListItem newEvent = list.Items.Add();

                        newEvent["Location"] = c.location;

                        newEvent["Heure de début"] = c.start;

                        newEvent["Heure de fin"] = c.end;

                        newEvent["Description"] = c.Description;

                        newEvent["Titre"] = c.Title;

                        //newEvent["fAllDayEvent"]  =;

                        newEvent["Catégorie"] = c.Category;
                        newEvent.Update();

                    //    SPView m_view = list.Views["Calendrier"];
                    //m_view.CalendarSettings = SerializeAccessors();
                    //m_view.Update();
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                }
            }
        });
}}
```

I succed to add the event to SharePoint Calender but this for all user.
i just want to add event calender to my personnel calender SharePoint , not visible for all users .
best regards

Comment: Is this an answer? If not, edit your post instead

Comment: this a half answer , I succed to synchronize the calender but not with condition roles .